# Summarizing data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I'm trying to filter and summarize a table of data in Python. I'm struggling with selecting the the years (columns that start with 'Y') and calculating the mean for each country in that year. Below is the last bit of code I tried. I'd appreciate any feedback:

My CSV is located at the following link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e6R9Tse_Zt3AcY0pPAObdX5XVYKt6ZufHMG7nWLABMQ/edit?usp=sharing

```
areac= Temp_Change.columns.get_loc('Area')
monthc= Temp_Change.columns.get_loc[8:65]
df = Temp_Change.iloc[areac:monthc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see whether this solves your problem.

```
dfg = Temp_Change.groupby('Area').mean().loc[:, 'Y1961':]
```

[image]

If you want to stack these `year` columns.

```
dfs = dfg.stack().reset_index()
dfs.columns = ['Area', 'Year', 'Avg_Temp']
dfs['Year'] = dfs['Year'].apply(lambda x: int(x[-4:]))
```

[image]